# How to check if a Active Directory server is reachable from an Ubuntu/Apache/PHP web server?

Tags: php, apache, active-directory, ldap

How can I check if my webserver which have Ubuntu/Apache/PHP is inside a windows active directory?

I have php-ldap and openssl php extensions enabled, but I still can not login using ldap.

the ldap bind returns false.

The code is the same that works on my local machine.

There is some network command line I can use from ubuntu to check it?

Or even a php function instead of ldap_connect and ldap_bind?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

this is the code I use to test the connection it works on my local machine and not in the webserver:

```
<?php
        $useremail      = 'myuser'; 
        $data['password'] = 'mypassword';
        $adServer = "ldap://my.veryowndomain.com";
    
        $ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
        var_dump($useremail);
        
        $ldaprdn = 'myveryowndomain' . "\\" . $useremail;
    
        ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    
        $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $data['password']);
        var_dump($bind);

        echo "1 ldap_error: " . var_dump(ldap_error($conn))."<hr>";
        ldap_get_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $err);
        echo "2 ldap_get_option: ". $err."<hr>";

        echo  ' >> 3 '. var_dump( ldap_errno() )."<hr>";
        echo  ' >> 4 '.var_dump( ldap_err2str( ldap_errno() ) )."<hr>";
        
        if ($bind) {

            $filter="(sAMAccountName=" . $useremail . ")";
            $result = ldap_search($ldap,"DC=myveryowndomain,DC=com,DC=br",$filter);
            
            echo '<hr> 5 result'."<hr>";
            var_dump($result);
            
            ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
            $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
            
            echo '<hr> 6 result'."<hr>";
            var_dump($info);
                        
            if ( $info['count'] >= 1 ) {
                $success = true;
                $usernome        = $info[0]['cn'][0];
                $usernetworkUser = $info[0]['samaccountname'][0];
                $useremail       = $info[0]['mail'][0];
                $userimage       = base64_encode($info[0]['thumbnailphoto'][0]);
                echo ($ret);
            } else {

                $success = false;
                echo '7 not authorized'."<hr>";
            }
        } else {
            echo  ' >> 8 '. var_dump( ldap_errno() )."<hr>";
            echo  ' >> 9 '.var_dump( ldap_err2str( ldap_errno() ) )."<hr>";
            $success = false;
            echo '10 Fail to connect to'."<hr>";            
        }

        if (ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)) {
            echo "Using LDAPv3<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to set protocol version to 3";
        }
        
        @ldap_close($ldap);
```

Comment: It is very hard to give you any advice given that we do not know what you have tried so far. Adding code or commands you have tried to the question makes it much easier to provide help.

Comment: Hi, @heiglandreas i just add the hpp code i use to test the connection

Comment: remove the "@" in front of the commands. That will give you some more informations

Comment: for ldap_connect i get this return : resource(2, ldap link),
for ldap_bind i get this return : boolean false
for ldap_error of ldap_bind i get this return : null

Comment: what do the log files say? There should be an entry in the PHP error log